# wordpress mediaelements.js sreaming support shortcode

Tags: wordpress, mediaelement.js

As we now mediaelements.js works well on wordpress post with any audio video link with full address like  http://audio.mp3  or http://video.mp4

we can use shortcode like this [audio src="audio.mp3 "]

and all works well. But.. how i can do that with streaming URL?

http://livestream.rfn.ru:8080/rrzonam/mp3_128kbps

```
[audio src="http://livestream.rfn.ru:8080/rrzonam/mp3_128kbps"]

[audio mp3="http://livestream.rfn.ru:8080/rrzonam/mp3_128kbps"]
```

is not work.
I cheated a little bit:

```
[audio mp3="http://livestream.rfn.ru:8080/rrzonam/mp3_128kbps?.mp3"]
```

and this work but... it is not true way)
Can you say to me true way creating streaming with shortcode in wordpress without third party scripts and plugins?

Comment: **Why**, *why*, it is not `"true way"`? It works out of the box, man, no plugins, nothing. **It is** perfect, no!?

Comment: That's a great solution!